# function in CakePHP Model returning int instead of null

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a model called Api.

Which I'm accessing from a shell Script.

My shell script function that is running:

```
public function verifyTransactions(){
        $result =$this->out($this->Api->verifyNumber());
        $this->out(var_dump($result));
    }
```

this outputs]

```
int(2)
```

Here is the function in the Api model:

```
    public function verifyNumber(){
    return null;
}
```

I've tried making return null into return false (boolean) ,  return a string like "jibberish"

But still when I print it out I get the type as int with a different number in, like an object reference or something.

I'm sure I've over looked something real simple, if somebody could point it out that would be awesome ;)

Thanks

Edit:

> Ah the error is I've got $this->out in there twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to output the returned (null) value and just want to use it for comparisions, why not avoid using $this->out alltogether?

Leave your Api method exactly the same and the verifyTransaction method could simply be ...

```
public function verifyTransactions(){
    var_dump($this->Api->verifyNumber());
}
```

Or ..

```
public function verifyTransactions(){
    if(is_null($this->Api->verifyNumber()){
        //do null stuff. Could even use the out method you have been trying to avoid...
        $this->out('got null back from Api');
    }
}
```

Currently you are setting a variable with the $this->out helper... $this->out is meant for handling readable output, never for setting variables... Don't do ...

```
 $result =$this->out($this->Api->verifyNumber());
```

Just ...

```
 $result = $this->Api->verifyNumber();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Shell::out()` returns the number of bytes written or `false` on error, so I'm not sure why you would expect it to return something else.

See **http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Shell.html#_out**

If you need to reuse the return value of `Api::verifyNumber()`, then you should directly store it in a variable first.

```
public function verifyTransactions(){
    $result = $this->Api->verifyNumber();
    $this->out($result);
    // ...
}
```